# 'function' object is not iterable - Pathfinding

Tags: python, funciones

estoy haciendo un pathfinding y al hacer la función de draw (para que se llene el tablero) me salta este traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\msi\Desktop\Phyton proyectos\Projects\Pathfinding.py", line 134, in <module>
    main(WIN, WIDTH)
  File "c:\Users\msi\Desktop\Phyton proyectos\Projects\Pathfinding.py", line 111, in main
    draw(win,grid, ROWS, width)
  File "c:\Users\msi\Desktop\Phyton proyectos\Projects\Pathfinding.py", line 87, in draw
    for row in grid:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Se que el error es claro, la función no es iterable, el problema es que sin esto, no hay manera de hacer el pygame.fill o win.fill, este es el código de la función

```
def draw(win, grid, rows, width):
    win.fill(WHITE)

    for row in grid:
        for node in row:
            node.draw(win)

    drawGrid(win, rows, width)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Tambien anteriormente he definido la funcion makeGrid para crear el grid, donde por primera vez menciono al node= Node()

```
def makeGrid(rows, width):
    grid = []
    gap = width // rows
    for i in range(rows):
        grid.append([])
        for j in range(rows):
            node = Node(i,j, gap, rows)
            grid[i].append(node)
    return makeGrid
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cual es la solución?

EDIT: Código de la clase

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, row,col,width,rows_total):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.x = row * width
        self.y = col * width
        self.color = GREY
        self.neighbors = []
        self.width = width
        #self.height = height
        self.rows_total = rows_total
```

Código de la variable definida

```
def makeGrid(rows, width):
    grid = []
    gap = width // rows
    for i in range(rows):
        grid.append([])
        for j in range(rows):
            node = Node(i,j, gap, rows)
            grid[i].append(spot)
    return grid
```

Comment: `return makeGrid` retorna una función. ¿No debería retornar `grid`? No tiene sentido iterar llenando `grid` si luego vas a retornar otra cosa.

Comment: @CandidMoe Justo al momento de subir el código al stack miré mejor y me di cuenta de ese error, pero ahora retorna otro error. AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'draw'

Comment: ¿Y qué es `Node`?

Comment: @CandidMoe perdona por no responder antes acabo de llegar a casa!

Comment: @CandidMoe Node es la clase y node es la variable donde guardo la clase con i,j,gap y rows. Para poder iterarla.

Comment: Bueno, si, pero ¿donde está definida?

Comment: @CandidMoe Lo he añadido al post, no me dejaba pasarlo bien por aquí.

Comment: No veo que la clase Node tenga un método `draw` ...

Comment: @CandidMoe ¿Por que iba a necesitar tener el método draw?  Draw es una función

Comment: Cuando dices `node.draw(win)` estás invocando el método `draw` de la clase `Node`. Ese método no está definido.

Comment: @CandidMoe Lo he podido arreglar era un error de tipografia, y lo que hago con node.draw(win) es invocar a una función que inicializa los self.color, self.x, self.y, self.width.

Comment: Si ya lo resolviste, puedes simplemente eliminar la pregunta.